# Scraping youtube playlist

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, youtube, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to write a python script which will fetch me the name of the songs contained in the playlist whose link will be provided. for eg.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foE1mO2yM04&list=RDGMEMYH9CUrFO7CfLJpaD7UR85wVMfoE1mO2yM04 from the terminal.

I've found out that names could be extracted by using "li" tag or "h4" tag.
I wrote the following code,

```
  import sys

link = sys.argv[1]


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

req = requests.get(link)

try:
    req.raise_for_status()
except Exception as exc:
    print('There was a problem:',exc)

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"html.parser")
```

Then I tried using li-tag as:

```
i=soup.findAll('li')
print(type(i))
for o in i:
    print(o.get('data-video-title'))
```

But it printed "None" those number of time. I belive it is not able to reach those li tags which contains data-video-title attribute.

Then I tried using div and h4 tags as,

```
for i in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'playlist-video-description'}):
    o = i.find('h4')
    print(o.text)
```

But nothing happens again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I have figured out what was happening. My code was perfect and it works fine, the problem was that I was passing the link as an argument from the terminal and co-incidentally, the link contained some symbols which were interpreted in some other fashion for eg. ('&').
Now I am passing the link as a string in the terminal and everything works fine. So dumb yet time-consuming mistake.

Comment: "My code was perfect"  Clearly! 

Comment: haha!! I was a student and new to stack overflow that time.. your comment notified me and after seeing my post, feeling embarrassed :')

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foE1mO2yM04&list=RDGMEMYH9CUrFO7CfLJpaD7UR85wVMfoE1mO2yM04'

data = requests.get(url)
data = data.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

h4 = soup.find_all("h4")
for h in h4:
    print(h.text)
```

output:

```
      Mike Posner - I Took A Pill In Ibiza (Seeb Remix) (Explicit)


      Alan Walker - Faded


      Calvin Harris - This Is What You Came For (Official Video) ft. Rihanna


      Coldplay - Hymn For The Weekend (Official video)


      Jonas Blue - Fast Car ft. Dakota


      Calvin Harris & Disciples - How Deep Is Your Love


      Galantis - No Money (Official Video)


      Kungs vs Cookin’ on 3 Burners - This Girl


      Clean Bandit - Rockabye ft. Sean Paul & Anne-Marie [Official Video]


      Major Lazer - Light It Up (feat. Nyla & Fuse ODG) [Remix] (Official Lyric Video)


      Robin Schulz - Sugar (feat. Francesco Yates) (OFFICIAL MUSIC VIDEO)


      DJ Snake - Middle ft. Bipolar Sunshine


      Jonas Blue - Perfect Strangers ft. JP Cooper


      David Guetta ft. Zara Larsson - This One's For You (Music Video) (UEFA EURO 2016™ Official Song)


      DJ Snake - Let Me Love You ft. Justin Bieber


      Duke Dumont - Ocean Drive


      Galantis - Runaway (U & I) (Official Video)


      Sigala - Sweet Lovin' (Official Video) ft. Bryn Christopher


      Martin Garrix - Animals (Official Video)


      David Guetta & Showtek - Bad ft.Vassy (Lyrics Video)


      DVBBS & Borgeous - TSUNAMI (Original Mix)


      AronChupa - I'm an Albatraoz | OFFICIAL VIDEO


      Lilly Wood & The Prick and Robin Schulz - Prayer In C (Robin Schulz Remix) (Official)


      Kygo - Firestone ft. Conrad Sewell


      DEAF KEV - Invincible [NCS Release]


      Eiffel 65 - Blue (KNY Factory Remix)
```

Comment: thanks for your response but it would be really helpful if you could tell me where I was going wrong..